# Get i18n text for specific locale

Tags: sapui5

I have two models of i18n:

- `i18n_en.properties` for English
- `i18n_ar.properties` for Arabic

**My goal here is to get the corresponding text for *English only* despite the detected language.**

The following function gets the text based on the automatic language detection.

```js
fGetText: function(sText) {
  var oBundle = this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle();
  return oBundle.getText(sText);
},
```

Is there a way to retrieve text for specific language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ResourceBundle.create` method for creating new one with giving locale param.

```js
ResourceBundle.create({
  url : "i18n/i18n.properties",
  locale : "en",
  async: true,
})
```

Documentation of `ResouceBundle` [here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/module:sap/base/i18n/ResourceBundle#methods/Summary).